# How to verify that two (version 10) QR codes have the same message?

Tags: qr-code, passbook

I'm making an [Apple Passbook](https://developer.apple.com/passbook/) Pass for a 3rd party, and the QR code that I need to show on the pass is actually made from another QR code by decoding it, because Apple only lets you specify the message for the QR code and not the actual picture of it.

For some reason, the Passbook-generated QR code is different from the original 3rd-party QR code, even though they appear to have the same message upon decoding. Both of them are Version 10 QR codes.

I've already figured out that this is due to different levels of error recovery.

How can I verify that the codes contain the exact same information (same encoding and such)?

Comment: @Velox The codes are meant to be machine readable, so I'm concerned about there being differences not visible in a consumer qr code decoder.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. A QR code is a QR code. Yes there are different recovery levels, etc. But if your phone can do it, then anything else reading them can probably do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decode them and compare the strings. There aren't "invisible" characters -- non-printing, maybe, but they would  still appear in the string.

Note that encoding can vary by choice of mask pattern and ECI segments.

Comment: I'm accepting because this is correct as far as my experience went (finally I just checked with the 3rd-party software).

What put me off initially is that the "raw bytes" as provided by the [ZXing decoder](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) were different, but I guess it was the encoding.

Comment: There are many layers here. Raw bytes are what you get after undoing masking and error correction, so they don't vary with these factors. But two identical strings can vary based on how they are encoding: alpha mode, byte mode, byte mode with an alternate encoding/ECI, etc.